# my column name has parenthesis because of which when i call insert in php it gives error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO state( state, sanction_percentage,
lt`(`1p`)`min, lt`(`1p`)`, lt`(`3p`)`min, lt`(`3p`)`, ht`(`415`)`min,
ht`(`415`)`, ht`(`11`)`min, ht`(`11`)`, tarrif, per_day_gen,
generation_limit ) VALUES('$state', '$sanction_percentage', '$lt1p_m',
'$lt1p', '$lt3p_m', '$lt3p', '$ht415_m', '$ht415', '$ht11_m', '$ht11',
'$tarrif', '$per_day_gen', '$generation_limit' )";
```

I have used escape on parenthesis but it gives error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`(`1p`)`min, lt`(`1p`)`, lt`(`3p`)`min, lt`(`3p`)`, ht`(`415`)`min, ht`(`415`)`,'

Comment: Okay, here's a _random_ question. Why on earth have you put parentheses  as part of a column name _at all_?

Comment: Use back-ticks.

Comment: Because the database already contains column name with parentheses .

Comment: back-ticks is also giving the same error.

Comment: Then I'd suggest changing it and updating your codebase. This is going to cause you nothing but problems for _literally_ zero gain. Show how you tried using the back ticks.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your query column names using `

So you need to have something like this if column name is like: `lt(1p)min`

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO state( state, sanction_percentage, `lt(1p)min`, `lt(1p)`, `lt(3p)min`, `lt(3p)`, `ht(415)min`, `ht(415)`, `ht(11)min`, `ht(11)`, tarrif, per_day_gen, generation_limit ) VALUES('$state', '$sanction_percentage', '$lt1p_m', '$lt1p', '$lt3p_m', '$lt3p', '$ht415_m', '$ht415', '$ht11_m', '$ht11', '$tarrif', '$per_day_gen', '$generation_limit' )";
```